# accessing identifiers from an extra level higher in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, parents

I am working on a project in JavaScript and I need to be able to access a pedant object's variables, that was created with a constructor function from within an function in a child object.

```
var myObject = function(){
   this.foo = 'stuff',
   this.bar = {
      bit: 'things',
      bite: function(){
         return this.this.foo;
      }
   }
}

var test = new myObject();
test.foo = 'blarg'

test.bar.bite() //<-- this should return 'blarg'
```

I'm rather lost at this point. I'd prefer to have as little bloatware as possible in this particular application. less because I'm limited in space, but more because I just don't like needlessly large things. And I like to understand everything I implement instead of blindly utilizing JS plugins and libraries.

EDIT: what I want is to have a template that holds a function within an object that references information from another variable within each instance of that template.

Comment: I'll revise my answer and post an update.

Comment: awesome, awesome, been banging my head over this for a while actually, still noodling around with it even.

Comment: Please note, code posted will return the error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` please revise, however I believe I understand the intention

Comment: ah, yes, "this." vs ":" the bane of JS programmers >.>

Comment: just define `var self = this;` on the first line of the constructor and replace `this.this` with `self`

Comment: does not seem to work, it doesn't throw any errors, but it isn't actually running the function

Comment: EDIT: seems like it is working, but now I need to make my function actually work the way I want it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent level properties on the object by keeping a reference to the current instance of `myObject`. See the snippet below for an example.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  var log;

  var myObject = function myObject() {
    var self = this;

    this.foo = 'test';
    this.bar = {
      baz: function baz() {
        return self.foo;
      }
    };
  };
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    log = document.querySelector('#log');
    
    var test = new myObject();
    
    writeLog('test.foo before change');
    writeLog('===============================');
    writeLog(test.foo);
    
    test.foo = 'foo was changed.';
    
    writeLog('Value of test.bar.baz() after change');
    writeLog('============================');
    writeLog(test.bar.baz());
  });
  
  
  function writeLog(text) {
    if (log.innerHTML) {
      log.innerHTML += '<br />' + text;
    } else {
      log.innerHTML += text;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested that, and it's not correct. What I need to do is create multiple instances of a master object, each with a sense of "self" so to speak. for instance, I need to be able to create say 'obj' and in 'obj' there is 'obj.foo.bar()' that references 'obj.thing' so when I run 'obj1.foo.bar()' it properly references 'obj1.thing' where 'obj1' is 'new obj'